# Python azure blob storage - append to csv file only if row doesn't already exist

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

Hi im trying to append to a csv file in an azure storage account from a python script, however originally i was overwriting this file but i realised that actually i needed some of the content to stay in the file but any new content to be put in there aswell but without all the old stuff thats already in there. An example would be like below:

local csv:

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| One | value1 |
| Two | value2 |

azure remote csv file:

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| One | value1 |
| three | value3 |

So with doing an overwrite here would mean i would *lose* the `ID:three value:value3` here, and doing an append would mean i would *duplicate* the `ID:one value:1`

---

Heres the code i have so far:

```py
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient

container_client = ContainerClient(account_url=url, container_name=name, credential=creds)

container_client.upload_blob(name=file, data=data, overwrite=True)
```

This is what i currently have setup, so the question would be about that overwrite part, do i need to maybe download the file first do the analysis then reupload using overwrite, or is there a better method ?

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Firstly uploaded 2 files like below to azure storage account:

[image]

File1 Content:

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| One | value1 |
| Two | value2 |

[image]

File2 Content:

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| One | value1 |
| three | value3 |

[image]

Then used below code to append the both with unique values:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
import os
import pandas as pd

acc_name = 'rithwik1'
acc_key  = 'fAHYt5ISq+AStD8hnfQ=='
cont_name = 'rithwik'

b_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f'https://{acc_name}.blob.core.windows.net', credential=acc_key )

con_client = b_service_client.get_container_client(cont_name)

f1 = 'file1.csv'
b_client_1 = con_client.get_blob_client(f1)
with open(f1, "wb") as my_blob:
    download_stream = b_client_1.download_blob()
    my_blob.write(download_stream.readall())

f2 = 'file2.csv'
b_client_2 = container_client.get_blob_client(f2)
with open(f2, "wb") as my_blob:
    download_stream = b_client_2.download_blob()
    my_blob.write(download_stream.readall())

df1 = pd.read_csv(f1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(f2)

new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()

newfile = "emo.csv"
b_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=cont_name, blob=newfile )
csv_string = new_df.to_csv(index=False)
csv_bytes = csv_string.encode()
b_client.upload_blob(csv_bytes, overwrite=True)

os.remove(f1)
os.remove(f2)
```

[image]

Here ,
f1 is existing file.
f2 is new file from local uploaded to azure.

New file `emo.csv` got created as below:

[image]

Now its contents:

[image]

[image]

Try to follow the above process and you will get output(unique rows) as I have got.